# Wrong number of sentence count

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to count the number of sentences in a text but I do not get the correct number anytime I run this line.

```
import re

n = input("Text: ")

sent = len(re.split(r'[.!?]+', n))
print(f"{sent}", end="")
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of input and expected output?

Comment: The last element of `re.split(r'[.!?]+', n)` will be `..., '']` as there will be a `[.!?]` at the end of the sentence, which is extra.

Comment: And what about "Mr. and Mrs. John Doe use Dr. Adams as their family doctor."